How to plot multiple signals side by side in the same plot, with signal numbers on the x axis?
I have multiple files from different receptors that I'd like to plot together in a single graph. To achieve this, I could globally scale the data to smooth it. The problem is that I don't know if it is possible to plot this data side by side using a single plot. I know how to create subplots, but each one appears with blank spaces and axes between them. The idea is to obtain a more homogeneous figure like the one shown below:
.
I have tried to use subplots, but I need a cleaner figure like in the example. I noticed some examples like plot 3 graphs here in the Stack Overflow, but I need to preserve the sequential number information of the receivers on the x-axis.
I wrote the code below after furas tip:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stack = np.loadtxt("Stack/2D_stack.semd", skiprows=1)
ncols = stack.shape[1]

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))

val = 0.5  # 0.015
shift = val
for i in range(1, ncols):
    if i == 1:
        plt.plot(stack[:, i], stack[:, 0], '-k')
    else:
        plt.plot(stack[:, i]+shift, stack[:, 0], '-k')
        shift += val

plt.ylabel("time (s)")
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
fig1.tight_layout()
plt.show()

The output is close to the desired, but I'd like to have numbers from 1 to 96 on the x-axis to mark the receptor numbers instead of the actual values. The code output can be shown in the next figure:

Originally, every signal oscillates around zero. An enhancement in the visualization would be to paint in black between zero and where the signal is greater than zero for every trace.

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

maybe if you would use the same ax in all plots then you would have all on one plot - but it would need to shift/move right every signal to draw it next to each other, not on top of each other

You get to 48 on the x axis because you add 0.5 to every signal for 96 signals. Why not set val = 1 instead of val = 0.5?

Thanks for the suggestion pho. Indeed, it is the easiest option for this case, but the amplitudes of the signals can vary, overlapping the traces. So I can't guarantee that val = 1 will always work. I believe that I need a way to change the x-axis values without changing the plot itself. I'm still researching that.


Here you have

a method to normalize and shift a collection of signals
a simple way of plotting the normalized, shifted signals
how to place an individual minor tick mark for every signal

and also a way to represent the non normalized values of the signals, using LineCollection and ad hoc color mapping. This part is of course optional, but it seems to me that it fits with your desire of an enhancement, expressed in the last sentence of your post.
That said, we need something more than the usual imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import TwoSlopeNorm
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

We need a function to make a sequence of segments
mks = lambda x, y : np.stack((np.c_[x[:-1],x[1:]],
                              np.c_[y[:-1],y[1:]]), axis=2)

Here I assume a number of signals, the time array, and I generate  the v array with the signals in its columns. Of course you just read this stuff from your data file…
N = 60 ; rd = np.random.random

t = np.linspace(0, 2.048, 1025)
# compute a base frequency so that we have ~30 cycles
T0 = 2.048/30
w0 = 2*np.pi/T0

v = np.array(
    [np.sin(w0*(1-(0.4+0.5*rd())*np.sin(t))*t)*
     (1+rd()+np.sin(10*t-8*rd())) for _ in range(N)]).T

I normalize v to [-0.5, 0.5] the set of signals, and add to each one an appropriate shift
n = ( (v-v.min())/(v.max()-v.min())-0.5 ) + np.arange(1, N+1)

Plotting, to represent the values in v we need a norm and a colormap (remember to use a diverging colormap, here I've chosen seismic, but there are many others)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4), layout='constrained')

norm = TwoSlopeNorm(0, v.min(), v.max())
cmap = plt.get_cmap('seismic')

We need the loop over the normalized+shifted signals for plotting and the non-normalized, non-shifted signals to do the color mapping
for x, f in zip(n.T, v.T):

For each pair, we compute the sequence of segments in screen coordinates, we normalize the signal using our TwoSlopeNorm and compute a list of corresponding colors, create the LineCollection object and add it to the Axes
    segments = mks(x, t)
    f = (f[:-1]+f[+1:])/2
    normalized = norm(f)
    colors = cmap(normalized)
    lc = LineCollection(segments, colors=colors, linewidths=1.6, zorder=2)
    ax.add_collection(lc)

Finally, we plot a fine black line over each of the multicolored lines (this has the added benefit of sizing correctly the x- and y-axis), to make more visible the spans where the color is white, add a colorbar, invert the y-axis and add a minor tick for each curve
ax.plot(n, t, c='k', lw=0.8, zorder=4)
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(norm, cmap), ax=ax, pad=0.03, aspect=60)
ax.yaxis.set_inverted(True)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))

Time to show our work!
plt.show()


Thanks for the well-explained answer !! I'll try that.
